# Can any one tell me the books for power series?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, power-series

Can any one tell me the books for power series? I want to find the power series for sqrt(x). I surf on the internet but there is no success.

So please tell me the name of the book where I can find the power series of sqrt(x)/

Comment: You can easily find it yourself, for example from the definition. You will need to expand about an $a\ne 0$.

Comment: A book is [Abramuwitz & Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_15.htm) You can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BSqrt%5B1%2Bx%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+0.5%7D%5D&dataset=) which is documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingPowerSeriesExpansions.html). Look up wikipedia for [square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Properties). Note the comment of @André Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few sites where you can find useful information
http://hardycalculus.com/calcindex/IE_powerseriestables.htm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series
https://www.projectrhea.org/rhea/index.php/PowerSeriesFormulas
http://www.reading.ac.uk/AcaDepts/sp/PPLATO/imp/h-tutorials/series_02_power.pdf